# Why does my MessageBox show so many times?

Tags: .net, vb.net

*I have an application which blocks certain websites using a list of websites from the **`hosts`** file, and once that website is blocked, an event is raised, which in my case, a **`MessageBox`** is shown.*

**The program works great**, besides ***1*** annoying error which I can't seem to resolve, and that is, the `MessageBox` appears about ***6*** times, then, after those ***6*** times finishes up, the ***`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`*** page appears.

Is there a way to limit the amounts of times a `MessageBox` is aloud to show, but also letting the traffic come through to get  to the blocked website?

**This is** ***all*** **of the code I'm using:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim blocker As BlockListener
        Dim thread As Thread
        blocker = New BlockListener
        thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf blocker.listen))
        thread.Start()
        AddHandler blocker.Blocked, AddressOf User_Blocked

    End Sub

    Private Sub User_Blocked()
        MessageBox.Show("Website successfully blocked!") <-- Shows 6 times!
    End Sub

    Public Class BlockListener
        Private port As Integer = 80
        Private listener As TcpListener
        Private BlockUsers As Boolean = True
        Public Event Blocked As EventHandler

        Public Sub listen()

            listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port)

            listener.Start()

            While (BlockUsers)
                Dim clientConnection As TcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient

                clientConnection.Close()

                RaiseEvent Blocked(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End While
            '
            listener.Stop()
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your code hits the while statement 6 times.
While BlockUsers parameters is true, it will show the message and you try yo close the same connection 6 times.

```
      While (BlockUsers)
            Dim clientConnection As TcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient

            clientConnection.Close()

            'Set your parameter to False in order to do the transaction only one time.
            BlockUsers = False

            RaiseEvent Blocked(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End While

        BlockUsers = True
```

Comment: Works well! Is there a way to wait for say 10 seconds until BlockUsers is equal to True? I've tried using `Timer1.Start()` in the listen() sub, but I get error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: You can try this but I am not sure if that is what you need ?  Thread.Sleep(10000);

Comment: I used that after `BlockUsers = False`, then put `BlockUsers = True`, but then it waits for 10 seconds for the dialog to show up before I've even got to the website. @Coskun Ozogul